# Ошибка turtle: AttributeError

Tags: python, turtle

Ошибка `AttributeError: partially initialized module 'turtle' has no attribute 'circle' (most likely due to a circular import)`

```
import turtle 
from random import choice
from random import random
import time
t=turtle
colors=["red","blue","green","yellow","purple",]
chisla=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90]
defrr=["forward","back","right","left","speed","color","shape",'circle']
circler=[10,1,25,]
speedr=[10,5,25,15]

shaper=["turtle","circle"]
while True:
    chislo=choice(chisla)
    der=choice(defrr)
    colorr=choice(colors)
    shaperr=choice(shaper)
    speedrr=choice(speedr)
    if der == "forward":
        t.forward(chislo)
    elif der =="back":
        t.back(chislo)
    elif der =="right":
        t.right(chislo)
    elif der =="left":
        t.left(chislo)
    elif der =="color":
        t.color(colorr)
    elif der=="shape":
        t.shape(shaperr)
    elif der =="speed":
        t.speed(speedrr)
    elif der=="circle":
        t.circle(choice(circler))
```

Comment: Если с этим кодом есть какая-то проблема, то опишите её внятно, а не непонятным набором букв в заголовке

Comment: ошибка `circular import` может возникать, когда имя файла с кодом совпадает с названием импортируемой библиотеки

Comment: У вас ошибка уже в третьей строке: t = turtle . Что это?

Comment: @Volk, это, похоже, неумелая замена названия модуля своим именем. Обычно это делается так: `import turtle as t`, но, очевидно, автор вопроса не знал об этом способе.

Comment: @Volk и ошибки тут никакой нет. Так тоже можно делать, хотя это не по-питоновски.

Comment: Кстати, функции `choice` и `random` можно импортировать одной строкой: `from random import choice, random`.

Comment: @Глеб, спасибо! Буду знать

Answer (score 2):

Либо у вас в папке лежат какие-то *ваши* файлы с названием `turtle.py`, либо файл с этим кодом называется `turtle.py`. Просто переименуйте их.